# ElasticSearch JS query returns all document instead of filtered

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

i am with this problem: ElasticSearch JS returns all documents when I try to filter them. I have two documents, only one that match with those filters, however ES returns all documents... There is no mappings created, only two documents created. I dont know what to do...

I'm using Node JS

```
  client.search({
    index: "yojuego",
    type: "user",
    query: {
      "filtered": {
        "filter": {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              { "term": { "userid": "123456789" } },
              { "term": { "type": "yojuego" } }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }, (error, response, status) => {
    if (error) {
      res.json(400, err);
    }
    else {
      res.json(200, response.hits.hits);
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in your search parameters, you need to enclose your `query` into the `body` parameter.

```
  client.search({
    index: "yojuego",
    type: "user",
    body: {                  <--- add this
     "query": {
      "filtered": {
        "filter": {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              { "term": { "userid": "123456789" } },
              { "term": { "type": "yojuego" } }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
     }
   }
  }, (error, response, status) => {
    if (error) {
      res.json(400, err);
    }
    else {
      res.json(200, response.hits.hits);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks you very very much. It works perfectly. Do you know why (or if it is possible) it does not work if there a field named id? In the last example, replace "userid" to "id". Thanks

Comment: No reason it wouldn't work. what makes you think that?

Comment: Hi again, you know I'm into trouble again, now, it 's not fetching any document... It seems like It is not working no longer suddenly. I am very confused...

Comment: Maybe create a new specific question for this